# UINT GetDriveTypeA(LPCSTR)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'LPCWSTR' to 'LPCSTR'?

Tags: c++, qt

I am getting this error

> UINT GetDriveTypeA(LPCSTR)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'LPCWSTR' to 'LPCSTR'

Below is my code.

```
void USBDrives::add()    
{    
    QDir driveList;    
    for(QFileInfo drive : driveList.drives())    
    {   
        QString driveLetter = drive.absoluteFilePath();   
        LPCWSTR driveType =  (const wchar_t*) driveLetter.utf16();   
        if(GetDriveType(driveType) == 2)   
        {    
            emit sendUSBDriveLetter(driveLetter);    
        }    
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows there are two versions of just about all functions: The ASCII version which takes "normal" narrow-characters strings, and they have all the `A` suffix (as in `GetDriveTypeA`); And the wide-character "Unicode" functions, which are identified by their `W` suffix.

You can select between them by defining the `UNICODE` macro, which will make the non-suffixed functions use the wide-character functions, otherwise (if the macro isn't defined) the narrow-character functions are used.

There are two ways to solve your problem:

1. Use the wide-character function `GetDriveTypeW` explicitly; Or
2. Define the `UNICODE` macro to force all Windows API functions to use the wide-character functions.

If you only use a few of the wide-character functions, go with the first solution (using the wide-character functions explicitly), otherwise it could be simpler to define the macro (solution 2).

Answer (score 0):

You are using multi byte character set and passing wchar_t* as argument.
Following code should work:

```
  LPCSTR driveType =  (const char*) driveLetter.utf16();
```